# Single item clickable at a time when using SmoothScroller

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have following Github sample : [A sample to showcase contact list divided into sections with group header](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts)

In Adapter class I have following code when user clicks on an item :

```
boolean expanded = contact.isExpanded();
contact.setExpanded(!expanded);
notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

if (contact.isExpanded()) {
      mSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(getAdapterPosition());
      new Handler().postDelayed(() ->
         mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(mSmoothScroller), 100);
}
```

When I click on two of the items that has childViews at the same time, I get following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.start(RecyclerView.java:11377)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.startSmoothScroll(RecyclerView.java:8090)
        at com.sample.android.contact.ContactsAdapter$ViewHolder.lambda$onClick$0$ContactsAdapter$ViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.java:375)
        at com.sample.android.contact.ContactsAdapter$ViewHolder$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I don't want to remove `Handler.postDelayed`, rather I am looking for a solution to make only single item clickable at a time?

Comment: The commit in your sample says it's already solved, no ?

Comment: Can you show the entire adapter class please?

Comment: @LukasAnda, I found a solution as I shared as an answer, but I am unsure if it is the best way.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/ContactsAdapter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem by moving `setTargetPosition` to `Handler.PostDelayed` :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    mSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(getAdapterPosition());
                    mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(mSmoothScroller);
                }, 100);
```